# Displaying empty rows and also duplicate rows in listView android

Tags: android

This is my adapter where i am passing the products.

```
public class AdapterShoppingCartItem extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList();

    public AdapterShoppingCartItem(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView productName;
        TextView productMrp;
        TextView productSellPrice;
        TextView productItemInCart;
        TextView productTotal;
        Button plusButton;
        Button minusButton;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_shopping_cart_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            holder.productMrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mrp);
            holder.productSellPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sellPrice);
            holder.productItemInCart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            holder.productTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            holder.plusButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);

            holder.minusButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);

            holder.minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Utility.displayToast("minus");
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Product product = (Product) getItem(position);
        if (product != null) {
            ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants = product.getProductVariants();
            for(int j=0; j<productVariants.size(); ++j){
                final ProductVariant productVariant = productVariants.get(j);
                if(productVariant.getInCart() > 0){

                    String productName = product.getProductName()
                            + " " + productVariant.getVariant().getVariantName();

                    holder.productName.setText(productName);

                    BigDecimal mrp = productVariant.getMrp();
                    holder.productMrp.setText(mrp.toString());

                    BigDecimal sellPrice = productVariant.getSellPrice();
                    holder.productSellPrice.setText(sellPrice.toString());

                    int quantity = productVariant.getInCart();
                    holder.productItemInCart.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));

                    Payment payment = new Payment();
                    BigDecimal total = payment.calculateCost(quantity, sellPrice);


                    holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            productVariant.setInCart(1 + productVariant.getInCart());
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Utility.displayToast("plus");

                        }
                    });



                }
            }




            //if (holder.imageView != null) {
                //new Utility.ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(String.valueOf(brand.getBrandImagePath()));
            //}
            //holder.imageView.setText(brand.getBrandImagePath());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "shoppingCartItem is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return products.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

I just want to display the those products whose any of variant's in cart value is more than 0. But my above logic displaying lot of empty rows even though i have kept if condition.

Can someone help on what is wrong in logic? How to fix that?

Comment: what does `products.size()` return?

Comment: obviously number of products.

Comment: what integer value does `products.size()` return?

Comment: @pskink its 1900....

Comment: so you have 1900 items in your `ListView` since its adapter says so returning `products.size()`, if this is not you want change your adapter

Comment: I agree with you. But out of those 1900 items i just want to display items where this condition is true. if(productVariant.getInCart() > 0){

Comment: no, returning 1900 your adapter says to your ListView: `hey ListView display 1900 items`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your For loop int getView() method. As you have mentioned product size in getCount(). use the position value from getview method to loop through the Productvariant and display item with your cart count condition.

```
    ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants = product.getProductVariants();

     final ProductVariant productVariant = productVariants.get(position);
    if(productVariant.getInCart()>0)               
     {
  convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                      
  String productName = product.getProductName()
                                + " " + productVariant.getVariant().getVariantName();

                        holder.productName.setText(productName);

                        BigDecimal mrp = productVariant.getMrp();
                        holder.productMrp.setText(mrp.toString());

                        BigDecimal sellPrice = productVariant.getSellPrice();
                        holder.productSellPrice.setText(sellPrice.toString());

                        int quantity = productVariant.getInCart();
                        holder.productItemInCart.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));

                        Payment payment = new Payment();
                        BigDecimal total = payment.calculateCost(quantity, sellPrice);


                        holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                productVariant.setInCart(1 + productVariant.getInCart());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Utility.displayToast("plus");
     }
else
{
convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. this is the solution i was using before. But problem here is onbutton click i want to update product variant incart value. But with this solution it will update filteredProductVariant incart value. Also we have to have 2 different variables. I am just looking for a way where i can display items conditionally.